# Apache camel running on multiple nodes

Tags: apache-camel

I'm running apache camel on multiple nodes and source folder is same for all nodes.

All nodes are not processing files parallel, if node1 is  processing files then node2 is waiting to acquire lock of node1 locked file and not picking other files

I want all nodes process files parallel if node1 is processing file then node2 should go for other files except file1

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that all nodes get the same file listing and all nodes want to process the same file.

Try using the `shuffle` option so that every node gets a randomly sorted file listing.

Comment: Added shuffle param but still route not picking files in random order